# Is it possible to open a web page from a Cortana background app?

Tags: windows-10-universal, cortana

Cortana background apps provide [deep linking capabilities](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/cortana/voicecommands/deep-link-into-your-app-from-cortana), which allow the developer to link to a specific page within her app. I'm wondering if it's possible to open a different application instead, for example a web browser.

My current work-around is to deep-link into my app, and then call `Windows.System.Launcher.launchUriAsync` as soon as my app is launched. However, this means that the app opens along of the web browser. I would like it to not open at all! Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the MSDN page for [LaunchUriAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.system.launcher.launchuriasync.aspx):

> Unless you are calling this API from a Classic Windows application, this API must be called from within an ASTA thread (also known as a UI thread).

Unfortunately, Cortana's background task is not a UI thread. You're running as a background task, and communicating to Cortana's UI via a set of APIs provided for that purpose, which are limited by design.

Anything you try to do that requires you to be in the UI thread is going to fail for the same reason. You could try hosting the web control in your app however to remove the chain-launched browser from the equation.